# Linux Play

Tags: linux

Интересует команда(терминал) "play". Вопрос такой: что она делает, пример использования.

Comment: **man play** и **play --help** что говорит?

Answer (score 3):

Если сильно интересует, то есть несколько вариантов решения.

1. Запустить под отладчиком(дебагером) процессов. Столько забавного узнаете))))
2. Установить/скачать strace и запустить командой вида starce play что_либо.mp3, узнаете системные вызовы и что куда девается и куда сваливается.
3. Аналогично второму варианту, но использовать ltrace-покажет библиотеки, запускаемыеподключаемые при данной команде.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще она проигрывает музыкальные файлы прям из командной строки